# How to control transition of entering or exit activity depending on either it is returning to its previous activity or calling new one?

Tags: android, android-transitions

I have 3 activities where Activity A start Activity B, and Activity start Activity C.

A <=> B <=> C

So when I go from Activity A to B, I use

```
this.overridePendingTransition(R.animator.slide_in_left, R.animator.slide_out_right);
```

From Activity B back to A (using back key eg), it I'll have

```
this.overridePendingTransition(R.animator.slide_in_right, R.animator.slide_out_left);
```

Similarly, if I go from Activity B to C, I plan to use

```
this.overridePendingTransition(R.animator.slide_in_left, R.animator.slide_out_right);
```

And same for Activity C back to B, I plan to use

```
this.overridePendingTransition(R.animator.slide_in_right, R.animator.slide_out_left);
```

Now my problem is activity B has both transition depending it is called by A, or return from C. I create the back transition during onPause(). However this is not idea, as activity B will be paused too when it is calling activity C.

What's the right way (or right place to place the above codes) to controlling the transition animation that depends if it is creating a new activity, or exiting the activity?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen my answer ?

Comment: Sorry, just see it now.